# rapidjson document create nested object

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I want to create nested json object using C++ rapdijson::document functions.

Here is JSON I want to write

```
{
  "a" :
  {
    "b" :
    {
      "value" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

Using writer I can create it like this:

```
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

void main() {
    StringBuffer s;
    Writer<StringBuffer> writer(s);

    writer.StartObject();
        writer.Key("a");
        writer.StartObject();
            writer.Key("b");
            writer.StartObject();
                writer.Key("value");
                writer.Int(1);
            writer.EndObject();
        writer.EndObject();
    writer.EndObject();
    cout << s.GetString() << endl;
}
```

But when I try to use document I cant create nested objects using functions like SetObject() and AddMember() only creates JSON-objects with one level.

```
Document d;
d.SetObject().AddMember("a", "b", d.GetAllocator());
```

How to add nested objects into document or values created by SetObject and combine em into complex JSON file using document style?

Answer (score 3):

This code worked for me:

```
        Value valChannel;
        valChannel.SetObject();
        {
            valChannel.AddMember("sampler", c.sampler, w.mAl);

            Value valTarget;
            valTarget.SetObject();
            {
                valTarget.AddMember("id", StringRef(c.target.id->id), w.mAl);
                valTarget.AddMember("path", c.target.path, w.mAl);
            }
            valChannel.AddMember("target", valTarget, w.mAl);
        }
```

And last but not least add it to the document:

```
Document d;
d.CopyFrom(valChannel, d.GetAllocator());
```

This code is copied from the assimp-repo: [Assimp-Repo](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/code/glTF/glTFAsset.inl)